# Trouble Accessing Properties of a Custom Lookup Field in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, custom-field, lookup

I have a Visualforce page and I'm using the standard controller for the quote object.  I added a custom field to the Quote object, QuoteContact, which is a lookup data type.  Everything looks good on Salesforce Quote page, but on a separate VF page I need to display the name, phone number, and email for the Contact.

[image]

I have tried various options unsuccessfully. In short, `{!quote.QuoteContact__c}` will display the contact ID, but if I try to access any of the properties, e.g.`{!quote.QuoteContact__c.name}`, then I get an error:

> Error: Unknown property 'String.name'

Using an outputField tag, `<apex:outputField value="{!quote.QuoteContact__c}" />`, displays the name as a clickable link, but I don't want this to be in the form of a link, and I also need the email and phone number.

Can anyone help with this?  This seems like it  should be pretty straight forward, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field you are accessing is on the parent and you need to access it through **__r** notation instead of **__c**.

Use {quote.QuoteContact__r.field_api} and this should work.

Let me know if any other help needed. :)

Thank You.